# tensorflowについて:terminalから実行する場合とpycharmから実行する場合とで結果が異なってしまう

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm

tensorflowにて、文章予測の機械学習を学んでいます。最初はpythonのコードをメモ帳に保存し、Powershellにコピペして行っていました（①）が、Pycharmで実行することにしました（②）。
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/text_generation?hl=ja
のコードを用いています。トレーニング後に、保存されたチェックポイントを読み込む際に、今までの①の方法では、重みを読み込み、文章生成にも反映されていたのですが、②の方法では、重みが読み込まれていないようです。
EPOCH=100で学習した後の①、②の結果はそれぞれ以下の通りです。(最初の数十文字だけ書きます。)

①:オマエタチに告告した。ケータブさん。お祭えと申し合わせが10月15分を経つ物の話。老人は死んですか？」  ときかれた。誰も居を止める魔境になりたい」  じゃ、風のように巡りかけて…。

②:オマエタチは駒泉鄭別萎Ο供望合膳休孤軋巨赦輻友熨＝蹴執消ば輝+刃折錬★湖ュ拘拍昇雪閣査的ｇ卑律屑版菩穫ざ童腫己揮庭為ず募鉛姫責貧O鹿○猿
②の結果は、重みづけを行っていない最初の文章予測と類似していることから、重みが正しくロードされていないのだと思います。
正確に言うと、一つの.pyファイルでモデルの学習から文章生成までを行えば結果は①のようになります。
しかし、保存したチェックポイントを読み込み、モデルを構築し、文章生成しようとすると、②のようになってしまいます。①の方法では正しく出力されるにも関わらずです。
しかし、Pycharmで実行する際もエラーなどは出ず、トレーニングチェックポイントの読み込みの
`model.load_weights(tf.train.latest_checkpoint(checkpoint_dir))`
の結果は
`./training_checkpoints2\ckpt_100`
と読み込みされているようです。モデルの構築に関しても、参考サイトと同じものを用いています。

```
def build_model(vocab_size, embedding_dim, rnn_units_1, batch_size):
  model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim,
                              batch_input_shape=[batch_size, None]),
    tf.keras.layers.GRU(rnn_units_1,
                        return_sequences=True,
                        stateful=True,
                        recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(vocab_size)
  ])
  return model

model = build_model(vocab_size, embedding_dim, rnn_units_1, batch_size=1)
```

どのようにすれば解決できますか？
以下に、チェックポイントの読み込みから文章生成までのコードを書きます。

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os
import time
os.chdir('C:\\Users\\ahwes\\deeplearning_Pycharm')
f = open('C:\\Users\\ahwes\\Documents\\test\\source.txt', 'r',encoding="utf-8")
h = open('C:\\Users\\ahwes\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject\\output.txt','w',encoding="utf-8")
text = f.read()
vocab = sorted(set(text))
char2idx = {u:i for i, u in enumerate(vocab)}
idx2char = np.array(vocab)
text_as_int = np.array([char2idx[c] for c in text])
seq_length = 100
examples_per_epoch = len(text)//(seq_length+1)
char_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(text_as_int)
sequences = char_dataset.batch(seq_length+1, drop_remainder=True)
vocab_size = len(vocab)
embedding_dim = 256
rnn_units_1 = 1024
checkpoint_dir = './training_checkpoints2'
tf.train.latest_checkpoint(checkpoint_dir)
print(tf.train.latest_checkpoint(checkpoint_dir))
def build_model(vocab_size, embedding_dim, rnn_units_1, batch_size):
  model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim,
                              batch_input_shape=[batch_size, None]),
    tf.keras.layers.GRU(rnn_units_1,
                        return_sequences=True,
                        stateful=True,
                        recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(vocab_size)
  ])
  return model

model = build_model(vocab_size, embedding_dim, rnn_units_1, batch_size=1)
model.load_weights(tf.train.latest_checkpoint(checkpoint_dir))

model.build(tf.TensorShape([1, None]))
model.summary()

def generate_text(model, start_string):
  num_generate = 2000
  input_eval = [char2idx[s] for s in start_string]
  input_eval = tf.expand_dims(input_eval, 0)
  text_generated = []
  temperature = 0.8
  model.reset_states()
  for i in range(num_generate):
      predictions = model(input_eval)
      predictions = tf.squeeze(predictions, 0)
      predictions = predictions / temperature
      predicted_id = tf.random.categorical(predictions, num_samples=1)[-1,0].numpy()
      input_eval = tf.expand_dims([predicted_id], 0)
      text_generated.append(idx2char[predicted_id])
  return (start_string + ''.join(text_generated))

h.write(generate_text(model, start_string=u"オマエタチ"))
f.close()
h.close()
```